# \n won't work, not going to a new line

Tags: java, store, text-files

I'm creating a small program that saves a int value into a text file, saves it, and loads it when you start the program again. Now, I need 3 more booleans to be stored in the text file, I am writing things in the file with

```
    public Formatter x;

x.format("%s", "" + m.getPoints() + "\n");
```

Whenever I want to go to a new line in my text file, with \n, it wont go to a new line, it will just write it directly behind the int value. I tried doing both

```
        x.format("%s", "" + m.getPoints() + "\n");
    x.format("%s", "" + m.getStoreItem1Bought() + "\n");
```

and

```
    x.format("%s%s", "" + m.getPoints() + "\n", "" + m.getBought() + "\n");
```

but, both will just write the boolean directly behind the int value, without starting a new line. Any help on this?

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits, and my text editor is Eclipse, I am running all of the code with Eclipse too.

Comment: Are you using a Windows system? The `\n` will insert a linefeed, rather than the system-dependent line separator. On Windows that is a carriage-return followed by a linefeed. That might make it appear as though there is nothing in between

Comment: Right, but there are just few programs requiring `\r\n` and all I encountered shows lone `\n` as a box-like character (which is not the behavior described).

Comment: Weird. I'm using Eclipse on Windows XP and it works fine with `\n` only.

Comment: It may be my code around it though, i'm a new coder making lots of small mistakes. But, I got it working now though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More specifically, I would recommend using:

```
x.format("%d%n%s%n", m.getPoints(), m.getStoreItem1Bought());
```

Comment: Even better: `x.format((Local)(null), "%d%n%s%n", m.getPoints(), m.getStoreItem1Bought());`. The first `null` argument will prevent any localization from being applied.

Comment: This worked, placed it on a new line, thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 6):

Use this instead:

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Both of this options work. Your problem is in how you format the output:

```
System.out.format("%s" + newline + "%s" + newline, "test1", "test2");
System.out.format("%s%n%s", "test1", "test2");
```

Output:

```
test1
test2
test1
test2
```

Comment: That outputted 3nullfalsenull into my text file, didn't work either.

Comment: This really should work. Unless you're doing the output in the class initialization before `newline` gets assigned.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `%n` instead of `\n` when using format.  For details on this, please see the [Formatter API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) and search this page for "line separator" and you'll see.

Comment: My bad. I thought you were using a variant of the Formatter class such as is used with PrintStream's printf method.

Comment: This works only for `%n` in the format string part of the `Formatter.format` method, not in the arguments.

Comment: @maaartinus: yep.  I'm going to delete this answer soon and have up-voted the other better answers.

Comment: I do NOT think your answer should be deleted! It's the most sane way for dealing with the newline insanity (besides completely ignoring it, which is not always applicable). My comment was just a usage note to the OP, not a critique of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

No problem here:

```
System.out.format ("first: %s%s", "" + x + "\n", "" + y + "\n");
```

While I would prefere, to integrate the \n into the format String, not the values:

```
System.out.format ("second: %s\n%s\n", x, y);
```

Using Formatter.format works the same.

Comment: Don't use \n - that only works reliably on Linux systems (and modern Macs). %n or System.getProperty("line.separator") is the correct version. No need to write unportable code if the solution is hardly more work.

Comment: Depends on what you like to do with the product. If you need a "\n", use a "\n", if you need a portable output, use "%n". Modern editors (except Notepad, which isn't modern) often can handle both forms of input.

Answer (score 0):

Well your syntax is surely quite.. interesting. Why use the formatting method if you're just piece the string together anyways? Also since you nowhere say what stream you're using we have to guess a bit, but anyways.

Anyways I'm betting that 1. you're using windows and 2. that the editor (I bet on notepad) you're using only reacts to \r\n since that's the correct newline for Windows. To fix this DON'T hardcode \r\n in your code but instead use %n and use the printf function correctly (ie don't piece the string together!).

Otherwise if you really have to piece the string together:

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
x.format("%s", "" + m.getPoints() + newline);
```

will work.