# Java (Android) doesn't understand \n captured through a tcp stream

Tags: java, c#, textview

I have a problem with writing down the data I recieve through my C# server in an Android app. The app sends the server the function to give back a list of all running processes.

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
                        {
                            sw.Write(p.ProcessName + "\n");
                            sw.Flush();
                            Console.Write(p.ProcessName + "\n");
                        }
```

The Console output works perfectly fine, but at the recieving end I just get the first process in the list. The problem lies in the \n: I tried first building up a string, then flushing and with for-loops printing numbers. It's always the \n that fails. 
I'm printing in out into a TextView, if that helps. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: ***Your Java code*** doesn't understand \n captured through a tcp stream. You've provided none of it. That means that we have to guess at what the problem might be.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of sending "\n" to your client send "%d%n%s%n" Source: [\n won't work, not going to a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918139/n-wont-work-not-going-to-a-new-line)

Last option would be instead of sending the "\n" from the server you could write a byte and then on the android side you could interpret it as 
a "\n"

```
if(DataInputStream.readByte()==1){//Replace the 1 with whatever byte you want to represent the \n.
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){//Runs the code on the UiThread

        public void run()
        {   
        MainActiviy.TextView.append("\n");//When you get the byte you append a \n to your textview
        } 
   });
}
```

You would run this piece of code on a Network thread and it would update the Ui.