# Writing a String on a new line

Tags: java, android, string, bluetooth, newline

Try to write string in file in new line, although i added "\n" to the end of string but could not success code as below:-

```
Timer t = new Timer();

                t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (;true;){
                        String smsg = new String("$;TRIG;");
                        String neuline= "";
                        neuline =neuline +"\n";
                            neuline =smsg+"\n";
                        activeBT.write(neuline.getBytes());
                    }}
                }, 0, 100);
```

can someone help me

Comment: Assuming activeBT is a FileOutputStream?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918139/n-wont-work-not-going-to-a-new-line

Comment: try it with a specific CharSet like

`activeBT.write(neuline.getBytes('UTF-8'))`

Answer (score 0):

You may can solve it like this:

```
activeBT.write(smsg+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
activeBT.write();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with Byte Array:

```
byte[] mybyte= new byte[] {'$',';','T','R','I','G',';',13,10};
activeBT.write(mybyte);
```